# join with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I have a **tbl_categories** table as follows:

```
id  category_name   parent_id   status  category_order  slug
```

I have another table **tbl_users** where each user record can belong to a maximum of 3 main categories and 3 sub-categories in each main (So, total 3 main and 9 sub)

I know I can use aliases on the **tbl_users** table and create my query which will return the categories and sub categories a user belongs to. However, the table structure that i can think of for **tbl_users**  table looks something like this:

> id username password maincat_1 subcat_1_1 subcat_1_2 subcat_1_3
>   maincat_2 subcat_2_1 subcat_2_2 subcat_2_3 maincat_3 maincat_3_1
>   maincat_3_2 maincat_3_3

Is there a better structure/way to do this?

Comment: Thats a fine structure.
  
You could make a table linking cats to users, but then you'd have a more complex join query, plus have to enforce the 3/9 rule in code somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query subcategories belonging to a user:

```
SELECT t1.first_name, t1.last_name, m1.category_name AS maincategory_1, m2.category_name AS maincategory_2, m3.category_name AS maincategory_3
    FROM tbl_user_individual AS t1
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m1 ON t1.subcat_1 = m1.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m2 ON t1.subcat_2 = m2.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m3 ON t1.subcat_3 = m3.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m4 ON t1.subcat_4 = m4.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m5 ON t1.subcat_5 = m5.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m6 ON t1.subcat_6 = m6.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m7 ON t1.subcat_7 = m7.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m8 ON t1.subcat_8 = m8.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS m9 ON t1.subcat_9 = m9.id
    WHERE 
    m1.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m2.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m3.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m4.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m5.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m6.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m7.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m8.slug = 'english_1394435671' OR
    m9.slug = 'english_1394435671'
```

To know if the user belongs to the main category, the query will be shorter since there are only 3 main categories that a user can belong to.
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way:

Your structure for `tbl_categories` is fine.

Add another structure where you store your user-data:

```
id username password
```

Each user will be stored once here. Then add a "pivot"- or translation-Table `USERS_CATEGORIES` to connect both your `user` and `categories` table:

```
userID categoryID
```

Each user can be stored more than once here, eg three times for three main categories.

If you want to get all category-names a user is in you would do a query like this:

```
SELECT tbl_categories.category_name
FROM tbl_categories, USERS_CATEGORIES, USERS
WHERE USERS.username = 'My Name'
AND USERS.id = USERS_CATEGORIES.userID
AND USERS_CATEGORIES.categoryID = tbl_categories.id
```

The theoretical Background is called "database normalization" - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: you forgot about restriction, each user must be in 3 or less categories and 3 or less subcategories

Comment: Nope, I have that in the `USERS_CATEGORIES`. You can add the same userID several times for different categories. To differ between main- and subcategory you can add some flags in `USERS_CATEGORIES` eg

Comment: @Benni The way i suggested in the question requires inserting the categories in the same table where the user information is present. This means when user submits a form, his/her details + category details are stored in just one insert operation in one table. What is the motivation of creating a different table for categories which could have 12 records (3 + 9) for one user ?

Comment: The answer of @Benni is the correct way. The queries to database will be more simple, normalized and will use indexes more easily.